# Querying more than a 1000 tables per query?

Tags: google-bigquery

There is a 1000 table limit on queries. However, some of our datasets have over 1000 tables.

Any plans on increasing the allowed tables per query limit?

Answer (score 1):

While querying the union of a series of tables is a good pattern in BigQuery, there is a cost for this: Each additional table involved in a query makes said query marginally slower.

That's why there is a 1000 tables limit: Approaching this scale, the query gets noticeable slower, and alternative methods become more attractive.

Can you pre-combine said >1000 tables into a big one for queries that would require going through a lot of tables otherwise?

Comment: You're... answering your own vague question about Google's future plans with a question, and ignoring your own question?

Comment: That's the redacted version of a question I got via email, and thought others would benefit from making its answer public. Encouraged by http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: The final question in his answer is very clearly part of an overall recommendation: _merge the tables if you can_.  It's not complicated.